# Error in the pom.xml file for Maven version it shows following error ""

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.activiti.examples</groupId>
<artifactId>activiti-examples</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>BPMN 2.0 with Activiti - Examples</name>
<properties>
    <activiti-version>5.22.0</activiti-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.168</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <classpathContainers>
                    <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Activiti DesignerExtensions</classpathContainer>
                </classpathContainers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It shows the following error
    ""Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin' from the repositories [local (/home/prakash/.m2/repository), central (https://
     repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository""

Comment: Try to run in command prompt. If it works, then you can ignore in eclipse.

Comment: are you connected to the internet? or at work where you need to configure eclipse to talk to your proxy server?

Comment: I am at work connected to internet. But why we need to configure eclipse for proxy?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse right-click on the project and select Maven -> Update Project.

If the above doesn't work repeat the process with Force Update option checked.